# .htaccess file does not overwrite html and instead shows markup on page

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm building a personal website, and I want my url links to look like domainname.com/example as opposed to domainname.com/example.html

I'm using fastcomet for my webhosting service. Under my public_html folder I have a .htaccess file. Here is the code for my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

My .htaccess file and all my html, css, js files are under home/username/public_html/ and I've removed the .html extensions from all my html files. After I applied these changes, I tried to get http://domainname.com/example and I saw the html markup as opposed to the rendered html such as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<all my code .... />
</html>
```

Any suggestions on what I should do? I am placing the .htaccess file in the wrong directory? I also tried with and without the Ifmodule tags on the .htaccess file.

Thanks!

Comment: "I've removed the .html extensions from all my html files" - to clarify, you have literally removed the file extension from the HTML file itself? Or just from the URL that points to that file (which is what you should have done)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you should keep the file extension .html so you can have your files properly handled and your .htaccess to work as intended. It seems that in the meantime, you have actually posted the ticket to our Tech Support Team. Though there has been a slight misunderstanding regarding your request, a senior member of our team successfully excluded the processing of HTML and HTM files from the NginX service and they are now passed directly to Apache for your domain. As a result, all of your url links now look like domainname.com/example as opposed to domainname.com/example.html. Should you have any further requests, do not hesitate to contact us back!

Answer (score 0):

> I've removed the .html extensions from all my html files

This is why you see page code.

Rename the files back and use the following rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

FastComet Team here! Part of our shared hosting environment is utilizing NginX as a reverse proxy to the Apache web service. This means that static content, such as HTML files, is processed directly by NginX and not by Apache. This is why any rules that you apply to the .htaccess file of your website are not making any actual changes. The requests to HTML files will be processed directly by NginX and they will not be passed to Apache so the .htaccess rules will be ignored.

There is an easy way of resolving that. We can exclude the processing of HTML and HTM files for your domain or even your entire hosting account. This way, those requests will be processed by the Apache web server, instead of NginX. In this case, the .htaccess rules that you apply will be taken into consideration by the system and they will work without any issues. To achieve that, simply submit a ticket to our Technical Support team and we would be happy to assist.

Comment: Thank you. So in the ticket I just indicate that I want to exclude html processing of files on my domain, and then my .htaccess file will work. Do you know if I need to keep the file extension of my files as .html?